# How to convert <div style="xyz"> to [div style="xyz"] with preg_replace php

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I have an html string

```
$html = '<div style="background-color:#000;border:1px solid #000">
<b>Some Text</b></div><span>I have amount > 1000 USD</span>';
```

I want to convert it to this

```
$html = '[div style="background-color:#000;border:1px solid #000"]
[b]Some Text[/b][/div][span]I have amount > 1000 USD[/span]';
```

I have searched a lot on google to get some php script to convert html to bbcode but could not find. I don't know the regex. If you give me some idea, with example code, It will give me the startup.

If it could be done with some other php function, please suggest me that.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
$html = '<div style="background-color:#000;border:1px solid #000">
<b>Some Text</b></div><span>This is an other text</span>';

echo str_replace(array("<",">"),array("[","]"),$html);
```

http://codepad.org/kjKVCzjw

**output**

```
[div style="background-color:#000;border:1px solid #000"]
[b]Some Text[/b][/div][span]This is an other text[/span]
```

Comment: But It will also replace other "<" or ">" in the html string that user has used, I only need to replace tags.

Comment: @user2207240 Users mustn't use `<` or `>`. They should use `&gt;` or `&lt;`.

Comment: "but it will also replace tags, i only want to replace tags"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace`:

```
$html = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('[', ']'), $html);
```

Comment: But It will also replace other "<" or ">" in the html string that user has used.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is replace `<` with `[` and `>` with `]`. Simply use `str_replace()`.

```
$newString = str_replace( "<", "[", str_replace(">", "]", $StringInput) );
```